# Put An Image Inside A Rails Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, helper

Hullo,

I'm trying to make a website in ruby on rails and I'm building a helper to display a rating out of 5 as a series of stars. So far I have got:

```
def stars(score)
html = ""
if score >= 1
  image_tag "star.png", :alt => 'one'
else
  html << ""
end
if score >= 2
  html << (image_tag "star.png", :alt => 'one')
else
  html << ""
end
if score >= 3
  html << (image_tag "star.png", :alt => 'one')
else
  html << ""
end
if score >= 4
  html << (image_tag "star.png", :alt => 'one')
else
  html << ""
end
if score >= 5
  html << (image_tag "star.png", :alt => 'one')
else
  html << ""
end
end
```

but that does not seem a very good technique and it is writing out the html to the screen instead of showing an image.

Anyone have any ideas what I can do?

Thanks,
Haziba

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def stars(score)
  (image_tag("star.png", :alt => 'one') * score).html_safe
end
```